# Add a non-Weblogic trusted domain

Tags: weblogic, cross-domain

Is it possible to add a non-Weblogic server domain as a trusted domain of another Weblogic server?

I have checked the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/SECMG/domain.htm#SECMG405) and it only mentions how to configure cross-domain access between Weblogic server domains.